# How to deploy web application without restart jboss server

Tags: deployment, web, jboss, restart

i'm new to jboss server. I have jboss-4.2.3 server. I have many application in single server. I need to deploy my application without restart my jboss server. Is it possible? If so what are the options to do that?

Thanks in advance!!

Comment: JBoss-4.2.3 is really ancient. I would recommend that you upgrade to one of the latest AS7.x builds. JBoss4.x community has been inactive for several years, so it would be hard for you to get answers to more complicated queries.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you just have to move the application (ear or war) in the deploy directory, and JBoss will automatically redeploy it (providing you've the hot deployment scanner active). If a previous version of the application was already deployed in JBoss, it will be redeployed automatically as well.

But keep in mind that the hot deployment is not advisable in production environments, because depending on the application it may fail (for example, a common problem is that sometimes jsp aren't recompiled when the war is redeployed, so the previous jsp will still be sent to the user). If you still want/need to use hot deployment,  to try to minimize this kind of problems, you can configure JBoss to delete automatically the old jsp compiled classes setting the property `deleteWorkDirOnContextDestroy` to true in the file `deploy/jbossweb-tomcat55.sar/META-INF/jboss-service.xm‌​l`, that will make a safer hotdeployment.

Answer (score 0):

If your application is already deployed and you want to redeploy -->>

If jboss is running in  'Development-Mode' ,then you can use 'touch' to app/WEB-INF/web.xml (Or open web.xml and save ) by this way you are updating its timestamp.

If your application is new to jboss then ->>

put your ear/war to deploy folder server will deploy it.

Comment: yes. application already running.. i want reploy it.. but answer is confusing. because there is many web.xml file. can you give some more explanation?

Comment: @user1636102 There cannot be more than one web.xml in your application distribution. Open web.xml of **your application**, put some **harmless** space so that the application will automatically be scanned and redeployed by JBoss server.